# Do distinct irreducible representations have distinct characters?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $F$ be an algebraically closed field such that $char(F)$ does not divide $|G|$.

Let $(\rho,V),(\psi,W)$ be non-isomorphic irreducible representations. Then, are their characters different?

Let $C$ be a simple component of $F[G]$ and $L$ be a simple $F[G]$-submodule of $C$.

Then, it can be proven that $1_C=\frac{dim_F(L)}{|G|} \sum_{g\in G} \chi_L(g^{-1}) g$.

This shows that $char(F)$ does not divide $dim_F(L)$.

Let $N$ be a simple $F[G]$-submodule of $F[G]$ which is not isomorphic to $L$. Then, there exists a simple component $D(\neq C)$ such that $N\subset D$.

Hence, we have $1_D=\frac{dim_F(N)}{|G|} \sum_{g\in G} \chi_N(g^{-1}) g$.

Suppose that $\chi_L=\chi_N$. Then, we have $\frac{dim_F(N)}{dim_F(L)} 1_C= 1_D$. Since $C$ is an ideal of $F[G]$, this means that $1_D\in C$. Hence, $D=C$ and this is a contradiction.

So, it must be $\chi_L\neq \chi_N$.

Is my argument correct?